# How to use javascript/other method in order to print the date in a format, when requesting an image generated by a php script?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am creating a site using bootstrap to give weather updates at the beach.
[MY SITE](http://www.newbrightonweatherstation.co.uk)

The following php script requests the correct image.

```
http://www.ntslf.org/files/php/pltdata_tgi.php?port=Liverpool&span=4&from=20130821
```

the last set of numbers is the date backwards.

Basically I want this image to update in the page and be the correct date.
I tried using javascript but i couldn't get it to work

```
var var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDate();
```

here is the source code for the website:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
<h3>Tides</h3>
<p>Tides over the next 2 days</p>       
<img src="http://www.ntslf.org/files/php/pltdata_tgi.php?port=Liverpool&span=4&from=20130821" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
 </a>
 </div>
```

I can't work out how I would use javascript to change the img src to the correct date

EDIT
I now have and i'm still unable to make it work

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
      <h3>Tides</h3>
      <p>Tides over the next 2 days</p>     
    <img src="http://www.ntslf.org/files/php/pltdata_tgi.php?port=Liverpool&span=4&from=20130821" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
    <script>
            var d = new Date(); 
            var date = d.getFullYear() + '' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '' + d.getDate();
            var image = document.getElementsByClass("img-responsive")[0];
            image.src = 'http://www.ntslf.org/files/php/pltdata_tgi.php?port=Liverpool&span=4&from='+date;
    </script>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: What did you try that you "couldn't get ... to work"?

Comment: that obviously works fine, how do I input that into my img src

Comment: I would look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

Comment: so if I understand correctly the issue is that you now have the image url hard coded and you want to dinamically display the image corresponding to today's date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why aren't you handling this on the server? it would be as simple as placing `echo date('Ymd');` inside the image url:

```
<img src="http://www.ntslf.org/files/php/pltdata_tgi.php?port=Liverpool&span=4&from=<?=date('Ymd');?>" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

Comment: Hi @koala_dev, This is my first website build. Still getting used to it all, to you mean in a php script?

Comment: @BenWhite not in a PHP script, in your actual page... what do you have now? a file with `.html` extension? change the extension to `.php` and replace your `<img>` tag with the one I provided

Answer (score 0):

My javascript knowledge isn't really that great, but getDate() only returns the number of the current day, for example 21 for today. A really basic example is to combine it yourself:

```
var d = new Date();
var date = d.getFullYear() + '' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '' + d.getDate();
```

There might be a better solution, maybe with some kind of formatter, but I'm not that knowledgeable with javascript so I don't know of any on the top of my head. (Also, worth noting is that the months range from 0-11 in javascript, but I can't really explain why that is so and why it's inconsistent that dates starts at 1 and not 0 if you gonna do it that way...)

For more info on the Date object, there's a bit of that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Then to change the image, you'd do something like this:

```
var image = document.getElementsByClass("img-responsive")[0];
image.src = 'http://www.ntslf.org/files/php/pltdata_tgi.php?port=Liverpool&span=4&from='+date;
```

in a function where you want to change it.

Comment: Thanks @galaxyAbstractor that helps but I was kind of already at that stage. How would I include that in my image string?

Comment: Ohhh, I think I misunderstood what you wanted to do. I thought you wanted to update the image when a user for example clicked a button or something like that. If you just want to have it with the date set from the beginning it's better to do it server-side as someone else suggested. Keep in mind about timezones between the user and server tho, the date might not be the same for the user as for the server.